# Error in Json request :{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":44,"error":{"code":-32603,"message":"No such service method"}}

Tags: python, json, urllib2, gerrit, httplib

I'm trying to create a HTTPSConnection to this address: "android-review.googlesource.com" and send a json request.

This address: "android-review.googlesource.com" is for Gerrit code review system which uses REST API. You can find more information about the Gerrit Rest-api here:
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html.

Each review in Gerrit code review system is related to a change request which I tried to get the change request information with a json request. This is the url and request:

url = "/gerrit_ui/rpc/ChangeDetailService"

req = {"jsonrpc" : "2.0", 
  "method": "changeDetail",
  "params": [{"id": id}],
  "id": 44
      }

you can find the complete code here:

```
import socket, sys
import httplib
import pyodbc
import json
import types
import datetime
import urllib2
import os
import logging
import re, time

def GetRequestOrCached( url, method, data, filename):

  path = os.path.join("json", filename)
  if not os.path.exists(path):
    data = MakeRequest(url, method, data)
    time.sleep(1)
    data = data.replace(")]}'", "")
    f = open(path, "w")
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
    return open(path).read()

def MakeRequest(url, method, data, port=443):
  successful = False
  while not successful:
    try:
      conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("android-review.googlesource.com", port)
      headers = {"Accept": "application/json,application/jsonrequest",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "Content-Length": len(data)}
      conn.request(method, url, data, headers)
      conn.set_debuglevel(1)
      successful = True
    except socket.error as err:
        # this means a socket timeout
      if err.errno != 10060:
        raise(err)
      else:
        print err.errno, str(err)
        print "sleep for 1 minute before retrying"
        time.sleep(60)

  resp = conn.getresponse()
  if resp.status != 200:
    raise GerritDataException("Got status code %d for request to %s" % (resp.status, url))
  return resp.read()
#-------------------------------------------------
id=51750
filename = "%d-ChangeDetails.json" % id
url = "/gerrit_ui/rpc/ChangeDetailService"
req = {"jsonrpc" : "2.0", 
  "method": "changeDetail",
  "params": [{"id": id}],
  "id": 44
      }
data = GetRequestOrCached(url, "POST", json.dumps(req), filename)
print json.loads(data)
```

In the code id means review id which can be a number between 1 and 51750, but not necessary all of these ids exist in the system so different numbers can be tried to see finally which one responds. For example these three ids definitely exist: 51750-51743-51742. I tried for these numbers but for all of them I got the same error:

"{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":44,"error":{"code":-32603,"message":"No such service method"}}"
so I guess there is something wrong with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `url = "/gerrit_ui/rpc/ChangeDetailService"`?  That isn't in your linked REST documentation at all.  I believe this is an older internal API which is no longer supported.  I'm also not sure why your method is `POST`.

Instead, something like this works just fine for me:

`curl "https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/?q=51750"`

Comment: yes, they changed the structure. I found the new one :)